# Fluido Skin for Maven Site: Doxia Problem

Tags: maven, maven-site-plugin, doxia

I am trying to use the Fluido Skin for my Maven Site, but get the error:

```
Cannot use skin: has 1.8 Doxia Sitetools prerequisite, but current is 1.7.4
```

My `site.xml` contains the skin

```
<skin>
  <groupId>org.apache.maven.skins</groupId>
  <artifactId>maven-fluido-skin</artifactId>
  <version>1.7</version>
</skin>
```

and my pom contains:

```
  <plugin>
    <artifactId>maven-site-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>3.6</version>
    <dependencies>
      <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.wagon</groupId>
        <artifactId>wagon-webdav-jackrabbit</artifactId>
        <version>3.3.1</version>
      </dependency>
      <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.doxia</groupId>
        <artifactId>doxia-module-xhtml</artifactId>
        <version>1.8</version>
      </dependency>
    </dependencies>
  </plugin>
```

With `maven-fluido-skin` in version `1.6` everything works fine.

I do not know where/how I need to upgrade doxia. Can somebody guide me?

Comment: You should try to upgrade maven-site-plugin to 3.7.X and then it should work...see https://maven.apache.org/skins/

Comment: @khmarbaise Thank you, it works. The strange thing is that I now loose syntax highlighting in markdown..

Comment: Can you please tell where you have used the highlighting ..best would be a small example project....

Comment: @khmarbaise I have written a new question for this: https://stackoverflow.com/q/54596139/927493